# Remove duplicate variant in queryset in django

Tags: django, django-models

```
class ProductEntry(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="product_entries")
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=0)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    image = models.ForeignKey(Image, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="product_entries", blank=True, null=True)
    variants = models.ManyToManyField(Variant)
    inventory_management = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def get_variants(self):
        print(self.variants.values())
```

get_variants return bottom resut:

`<QuerySet [{'id': 3, 'name': 'Red', 'image_id': None, 'color': '#C80000FF', 'category': 'C'}, {'id': 1, 'name': 'Black', 'image_id': None, 'color': '#1F1F1FFF', 'category': 'C'}]> <QuerySet [{'id': 2, 'name': 'Purple', 'image_id': None, 'color': '#2D1952FF', 'category': 'C'}]> <QuerySet [{'id': 3, 'name': 'Red', 'image_id': None, 'color': '#C80000FF', 'category': 'C'}]> <QuerySet [{'id': 4, 'name': 'Green', 'image_id': None, 'color': '#009812FF', 'category': 'C'}]>`

As a result, red color has been repeated twice, I want to delete one of them

`self.variants.values().distinct("name")`

Answer (score 1):

You can get an iterable of distinct colors with:

```
def get_variant_colors(self):
    return self.variants.values_list('color', flat=True).distinct()
```